# addListener not working in Firefox Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I have created the following method for adding markers too my google map. These results are dynamic and is created whenever the map is moved.

```
function addMarker2(lat, lng, hid, label, map) {
    var price = label;
    if (price == null)
        price = "0.00"


    var marker = new RichMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        flat: true,
        //anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
        content: '<div data-hid="' + hid + '" class="map-tooltip">' + price + '&nbsp;</div>',
        id: hid
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    marker.addListener('click', function () {
    //marker.addListener('click', function (e) {
        // stop event from bubbling to map click event
        //e = e || window.event;
        //var e = window.event || e;
        event.preventDefault();
        // close any open infoboxes
        if (infowindow != null)
            infowindow.close();

        // find clicked hotel
        var hotel;
        $.each(hotel_json, function (i, obj) {
            if (obj.hid === hid) {
                hotel = obj;
            }
        });

        // build infobox html
        var contentString = '<img src="' + hotel.img + '" alt="" style="height: 150px; width: 100%"><a class="favourite-button toggle-select" id="favourite-button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></i></a><h5><span style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="javascript:;" style="text-decoration: none; color: #888">' + hotel.name + '</a></span><br /><div class="mt5 text-warning-custom"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div></h5><span>Guesthouse</span><p class="text-primary"><sup class="h6 pr5">R</sup><span class="h3">' + hotel.price + '</span><sup class="h6 pl5">ZAR</sup></p><div class="map-action-btns"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-block"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>&nbsp;Request Quote</a><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp;Book Now</a></div>';

        // open infobox
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 200
        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

If you click on the custom marker additional information gets displayed. The problem comes in with the event.preventDefault() this works fine on Chrome and IE. I have tried multiple solutions online and has had no success. Hopefully I am just missing something simple. All help will be appreciated. I have left some of the things I have tried in comments.

Comment: Check your console. FYI, FF doesn't use global event model, you need to pass it explecitely as parameter of event handler: `marker.addListener('click', function (event) {...});`

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick response. I have checked my console. If I add event like that it comes through as undefined in FF.

Comment: Oh ya, that's a custom method. Check arguments passed to it. I guess it should pass event object

Comment: There is no real object. This is called from return method of an API that returns lat and lng values. It then adds the markers on the fly.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion, long time i didn't used google maps API. Now what is your expected behaviour of using `event.preventDefault();` on google maps marker to do? Can you provide MCVE?

Comment: The prevent default just removes the default behavior for the marker. If I remove that it does still work but very buggy and slow.

Comment: try to add `google.maps.event.`
e.g. `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {`